# Mac OS X DNS issues with Google DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx

I am assisting another user with DNS issues & a golang bug with larger than 512 bytes.  On my machine the DNS resolution is much smaller than 512 bytes and does not include an authority section, but on the users machine it is much larger than 512 bytes due to the authority section.  What configuration / software might be causing this difference?  We are on the same version of Mac OS X as far as I can tell.

## My dig output

```
> % dig @8.8.4.4 api.heroku.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.4.4 api.heroku.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37856
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.heroku.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.heroku.com.         29      IN      CNAME   midgard.heroku.com.
midgard.heroku.com.     449     IN      CNAME   midgard.herokussl.com.
midgard.herokussl.com.  2758    IN      CNAME   elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 3 IN A 23.21.149.112
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 3 IN A 54.225.188.133
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 3 IN A 54.243.105.250

;; Query time: 76 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug  4 09:29:57 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 193
```

## The user dig output

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.4.4 api.heroku.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55215
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 12

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.heroku.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.heroku.com. 21 IN CNAME midgard.heroku.com.
midgard.heroku.com. 441 IN CNAME midgard.herokussl.com.
midgard.herokussl.com. 3137 IN CNAME elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 54.243.105.250
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 54.225.188.133
elb082153-1559744486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 23.21.149.112

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com. 140079 IN NS g.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS j.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS i.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS b.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS k.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS a.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS e.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS c.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS l.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS m.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS f.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS h.gtld-servers.net.
com. 140079 IN NS d.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
g.gtld-servers.net. 124660 IN A 192.42.93.30
j.gtld-servers.net. 91373 IN A 192.48.79.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 119024 IN A 192.43.172.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 119025 IN A 192.33.14.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 27063 IN A 192.52.178.30
a.gtld-servers.net. 16745 IN A 192.5.6.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 123106 IN A 192.12.94.30
c.gtld-servers.net. 153632 IN A 192.26.92.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 22933 IN A 192.41.162.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 107336 IN A 192.35.51.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 29637 IN A 192.54.112.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 119025 IN A 192.31.80.30

;; Query time: 48 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 14 07:37:57 2016
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 609
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be no difference in the queries and request headers. I expect the situation to be one of the following:

- A device on the remote user's network is intercepting the DNS traffic and mangling the replies.
- You are hitting different server farms. Both of you are sending requests to the same IP, but your requests are arriving at different destinations due to Anycast. As to why the servers are responding differently, only Google can answer that.

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq#anycast

> Google Public DNS uses anycast routing to direct all packets to the closest DNS server. For more information on anycast routing, see the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast).

It should be noted that the Additional and Authority sections attached to the second reply are unusual. When a recursive server is returning those sections, one would expect to see the nameservers for `heroku.com` and not the `com.` TLD. More than likely this is unintended behavior in the server software.